# Google Assistant Installation on Python3.6 OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.6, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install Google Assistant on OSX with Python 3.6.

I successfully ran this command:

```
python3 -m pip install "google-assistant-sdk[samples]"
```

But when I run this command with the path to the JSON file from the Google Cloud Platform:

```
python3 -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers --client-secrets /path-to/secret.json
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: No module named googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers
```

Also here's the python3.6/site-packages folder:
[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcXuI.png)

Seems that everything is installed but still it doesn't find the module.
Anybody can tell why and how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also paste the output of: `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: can you point me to the instructions you're following?

Answer (score 3):

The new version of the package use a different tool for negotiating the credentials.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets /home/pi/client_secret_client-id.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

See the updated documentation for the package on the [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-sdk/0.3.0).