# When installing Google Assistant, I an error "...googlesamples.assistant' is a package and cannot be directly executed..."

Tags: python, windows, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Alright, have been installing Google Assistant on my Windows 10 PC and have been met with multiple errors, the last of which I solved by going here: [Google Assistant Installation on Python3.6 OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070598/google-assistant-installation-on-python3-6-osx)

Now, I have everything installed, and want to test my mic and then start using the assistant. However, when I put in the commands

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.audio_helpers
```

and

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\robmak3>python -m googlesamples.assistant
C:\Users\robmak3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: No 
module named googlesamples.assistant.__main__; 'googlesamples.assistant' is 
a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I've been trying to follow this guide: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/

Any help fixing this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per version `0.3.0` of the SDK the gRPC samples are using a different auth helpers.

```
pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib[tool]
google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets path/to/client_secret_XXXXX.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype --save --headless
```

And you can launch the update gRPC sample with:

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
```

You should be able to follow the instructions from the [SDK package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-sdk/) and [gRPC package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-assistant-grpc)  page and explore the reference [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead:

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.audio_helpers
```

If you go to the following path you will notice that there is a directory named grpc inside assistant directory.

> C:\Users\%username%\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\googlesamples\assistant\

That is why you need to append .grpc next to assistant. And inside grpc directory you can see audio_helpers.py script.

To launch google assistant enter following command:

`python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk`

[image]

[image]